# Free WinMerge alternative with more clear line comparison

Tags: textfiles, winmerge, file-comparison

I use WinMerge to compare text files, usually alogn with TortoiseSVN.

It is pretty good.
The only thing which is inconvenient for me is very rough line comparison.

For instance, if I have two long lines without spaces and the only symbol is different in two string, WinMerge colors these two lines in the same color.

I want the similar tool as WinMerge (free, under Windows), but with more fine grain line comparison.

E.g. if I have old line

```
aa0aa
```

and new line

```
aa1aa
```

I want 0 and 1 be marked separately from the rest of the text.

Does exist something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried some alternatives already? http://alternativeto.net/software/winmerge/?platform=windows

Comment: yes, some appeared paid, for linux only, or non-working at all or not doing what I expected - and I am asking about specific feature, not the list of tools - your link is definitely even close not an answer. It is not clear for me why question is closed as non-constructive. I am looking for specific feature. Of course I can find and trying everything without Superuser, but I am asking because I expect somebody already had answer for my question and it seems to me useful for others to save time

Comment: Asking for alternatives that do something is often not constructive. In many cases, you're just approaching the problem the wrong way. Rather than asking for an alternative, ask about the actual problem yourself and let those who answer figure out how to help you — from Synetech's answer it  seems you didn't even need another tool to do this. Surprised? In any case, showing which alternatives you've already tried and why they don't is something we *do* expect here – even the downvote button says "… does not show research effort".

Comment: [Why is looking for alternative programs “not constructive”?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4383/why-is-looking-for-alternative-programs-not-constructive) — quoting @random, which exactly covers your case: *Try something - Show us you've done […] Be clear in failed efforts - Tell us what program you're currently using and what thing you can't seem to do or get out of it […] Your first port of call is to get it done in your current program. Should someone think another application would do better, they can proffer such.*

Comment: Thanks for explanations, but it is definitely rules of Superuser are not clear for me in this respect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WinMerge can do what you want. Just set the line-difference highlighting to character level:

[image]

Comment: Heh, this even better than I expected!